# How to parse reponse body from REST API when response code is 4xx in java

Tags: java, rest, http, oauth-2.0

I am trying to access REST API using OauthClient

```
try {
        OAuthClient client = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());
        OAuthResourceResponse response = client.resource(request, OAuth.HttpMethod.POST, OAuthResourceResponse.class);
} catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;
}
```

The api call returns a response body when I execute the call using Postman, but when I use this code above, it throws exception and I can not see the response body, in order to parse it.

Here is the exception:

```
org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthSystemException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 409 for URL:
```

Is it possible to parse the response body for 4xx errors

Answer (score 0):

You can build your response object in catch block and return like

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(new PresenterClass(ex.getMessage())).build();
}
```

Using Presenter class constructor

```
 Public  PresenterClass(String errorMessage){
    this.message = errorMessage;

    }
```